# SQL: use rank() together with aggregation function

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, dense-rank

Suppose I have a data table `data_table` containing an identifier `ID` and two values, `val1` and `val2`:

```
ID       val1      val2 
------------------------
1          3         4
2          2         5
3          8         9
4          1        -1
5          4        -2
6          5         3
7          6         6 
8          4         1 
9          2         9
10         4         1
------------------------
```

I want to multiply `val1` and `val2` and calculate the average of the two lowest multiplication values:

`avg(val1*val2 | rank(val1*val2) <= 2)`  (so that it is 100% correct, we assume that every multiplication gives an unique value)

I tried this:

```
Select avg(multipl)
FROM
(Select val1 * val2 as multipl 
from data_table
where RANK() OVER (ORDER BY multipl  ASC) <= 2 )
```

Unfortunately, Oracle-SQL gives me the error message: *window functions are not allowed here.*

I don't know what this error message means and so I neither don't know whether the code would otherwise work out (and be efficient). Does anyone have a clue how to handle this error message or how to write the code efficiently? I would appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `rank()`?  Your question doesn't specify how to deal with duplicates values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but the window functions needs to be returned from the subquery for filtering.  I would recommend `row_number()` if you want exactly two to be multiplied:

```
Select avg(multipl)
from (Select val1 * val2 as multipl,
             row_number() over (order by val1 * val2 asc) as seqnum
      from data_table
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

You can use `rank()` of course, but then the average might be of more than two rows.

If `row_number()` is what you want, I think this may more naturally be expressed by limiting the rows inside the subquery:

```
Select avg(multipl)
from (Select val1 * val2 as multipl
      from data_table
      order by multipl asc
      fetch first 2 rows only
     ) t;
```